# UITableView - create single delete button for multi-row section

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am looking to recreate the multi-row delete functionality of the Contacts App on the iPhone.

How do you get the single delete button centered?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom cell with a text box for each of the fields.  This could actually be done in interface builder, which I think you be easier to align the text boxes appropriately.

Click on the link below, this tutorial shows how to create a custom cell with a text box.  Just make the cell larger with more text boxes.  Not so bad.

Good Luck.

http://nadacode.com/2010/07/25/creating-a-table-based-form-on-the-iphone/